# Is it ok to have entities in different aggregates inherit from a common class?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have some common behaviour in several entities belonging to different aggregates, that I'd like to factor in an abstract class.

**Is there any drawback to have entities in different aggregates inherit from a common abstract class?**

---

## Use case

Several entities have name, description or other properties that can be translated in different languages.

For example, I would set a name with `setName(language, name)` and retrieve it with `getName(language)`.

Each text in each language is stored in an object, such as:

```java
class EntityName
{
    protected Entity entity;
    protected Language language;
    protected String text;
    protected int version;

    public EntityName(Entity entity, Language language)
    {
        this.entity = entity;
        this.language = language;
        this.version = 1;
    }

    // setText(), getText(), ...
}
```

For a given `Entity` class, `EntityName` is within the `Entity` aggregate. Only `Entity` can create, read from and write to `EntityName`, via `setName()` and `getName()`.

However, classes such as `EntityName`, `EntityDescription`, `OtherEntityName` would all share pretty much the same code. The only part than changes is a reference to the aggregate, and therefore the constructor.

Comment: Feel free to comment on the answers below. If something is unclear or not helpful, we can make adjustments to our answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't much on this topic. However, have a look at this article entitled [How To: Domain Driven Design](http://apparch.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Domain%20Driven%20Design)

In particular, read the section entitled *Step 2 – Identify Aggregates and Aggregate Roots*:

> In advanced situations, the presence of polymorphism in the class
>   model can affect the aggregate boundaries as well. This occurs **when
>   multiple aggregate root classes all share the same base class**

If you are storing book-keeping data (id, version, create timestamp, update timestamp) that is outside the domain model proper (e.g. to support your persistence layer), I don't see this as a problem. If, however, you are trying to reuse true business methods and attributes, you could consider replacing inheritance with composition or AOP introductions.

**Update**

After looking at the updated use case, it looks as though you are really trying to achieve code reuse rather than a true [Liskov is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) relationship. Some languages better support this type of reuse with concepts such as [mixins](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Category+and+Mixin+transformations) (Groovy) or [traits](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/126) (Scala). Assuming Java, one approach you could do is create a class and use Project Lombok's [@Delegate](http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html) annotation to forward to your implementation. This has the following benefits:

- Provides the same level of Aggregate encapulation
- Generates the bytecode for you without all the duplication in souce
- Allows you to save your one inheritence option for a true is-a
  relationship in the future
- Ensures consistency across your domain

I believe this to be purer and enables flexibility in your model. I've used Project Lombok on a few projects with great success. It allows you to side step some of the missing language features in Java and focus more on your domain than the necessary boilerplate code required to implement certain idioms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not the aggregates which share common behaviour, but entities within the aggregate. I've updated my question with my use case.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer to try to reflect your usecase.

Comment: I'm actually using PHP, which has support for traits, so that could indeed be a cleaner approach than using a common abstract class, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok as long as the common definition doesn't affect the aggregate root design. That is, you start modelling the aggregate roots and notice they have much in common so you extract a common base class.

I would think twice about this, though, because what are the odds that aggregate roots from different bounded contexts to have so much in common? It's a bit of a code smell IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not the aggregates which share common behaviour, but entities within the aggregate. I've updated my question with my use case.

Comment: Same anwser as I was referring to the Aggregate Root which IS an Entity

Answer (score 0):

Correct inheritance is defined by a `is-a` relationship. imho there are very few cases where that apply to aggregate roots.

Just because to roots look similar doesn't mean that they come from the same place.

If you can create a base class with a name which makes sense in the domain, go ahead. If not, do not.